# Nested Virtualization

Tags: cpu-usage, libvirt, openstack, optimization, nested-virtualization

I want to deploy openstack with nested virtualization enabled. Here is the scenario, on physical machine (Ubuntu 16.04) I have 2 VMs running,
1. kvm01 and,
2. cmp001

Kvm01: has 7 VMs up and running with different openstack services, with 68 vcpus.

Cmp001: has nova-compute running with 8 vcpus.

I have deployed the openstack successfully on nested VM environment, but VM inside kvm01 slows down after approx. 12 hours and I need to destroy all the vms with virah destroy and destroy kvm01 itself and start again and then everything works fine again.

I don't know what is the problem there and why VMs inside KVM01 are getting slow after some time.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 OS on physical machine, have 128 GB of RAM and 48 physical cores with 2 NUMA node, I have tried CPU pinning for kvm01 (pinned 42 physical CPUs to the kvm01 vm) but that didn't work for me.

Note: Current CPU model for kmv01 and cmp001 is host-passthrough, I have tried host-model which didn't work for me.

Hope this is clear. Please let me know in comment if XML file of kvm01 or cmp001 is required, or any other information required.

Thanks in advance.